# How to run select statement after stored procedure run ORACLE

Tags: oracle

I am new to Oracle, trying to run select statement after my stored procedure and failing. Here I am trying to return rows or any dummy data after my store procedure is executed, because my end process needs a return data for sure to make it consider as successful run. Is there any way I can trick it here is what I tried and failed.

```
EX: 

BEGIN 
  note.name;
END;
/
SELECT * from hello.table where rownum=1;
```

Error:

```
ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]ORA-06550: line 4, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/"
Activity ID: xxxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxx
```

Show return a single row after completion of stored procedure

Comment: You've tagged this as SQL Developer, but your error refers to ODBC - so is that really the client you are using, if it not what are you using, and how are you connecting? Whatever it is, it looks like you're trying to run multiple statements at once in a tool or mode that doesn't allow that.

Comment: you could return a cursor from procedure with the above query

Comment: Can you create new objects in your schema? One way to load and return data in a single statement is to create a function that first calls the procedure and then returns the results as a custom type. But it's usually easier to find a way for your application to make multiple calls; if you can add information about what program you're using, perhaps someone knows a way to make multiple calls.

Answer (score 1):

Code you posted looks OK. Demo:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test as
  2  begin
  3    null;
  4  end;
  5  /

Procedure created.

SQL> begin
  2    p_test;
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from dept where rownum = 1;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK

SQL>
```

Therefore, what exactly is your problem? What result do you expect?

---

If "at once" (as you commented) means that *everything* should be part of a PL/SQL block, then you'd declare a variable which is capable of holding the whole row, and then just `select` into it. `rownum = 1` condition prevents `too_many_rows` error.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    l_dept   dept%rowtype;
  3  begin
  4    p_test;
  5    select * into l_dept from dept where rownum = 1;
  6    dbms_output.put_line(l_dept.deptno ||', '|| l_dept.dname ||', '|| l_dept.loc);
  7  end;
  8  /
10, ACCOUNTING, NEW YORK

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Somehow my process doesn’t like / and thronging error as can’t recognize. I need to run them at once not like two different statements

Comment: What do you mean "at once"? Could you edit the question and post what you exactly did? Even a screenshot would help.

Comment: I edited the answer and added some more code. See if it helps.

Comment: your second approch runs but dosent retun any value. it should retun anything just one sample row

Comment: Exactly, it doesn't "return" anything - result is stored in a local variable. You can e.g. *display* it on the screen using DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE. See edited code.